# How to add parameters to all HttpClient request methods?

Tags: java, http, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing some Java code that uses Apache `HttpClient` version `4.2.2` to hit a RESTful 3rd party API. This API has methods that utilize HTTP `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. It's important to note that I'm using a 4.x.x version and not 3.x.x, because the API changed a lot from 3 to 4. All relevant examples I've found have been for a 3.x.x version.

All API calls require you provide the `api_key` as a **parameter** (regardles of which method you are using). This means that regardles of whether I'm making a GET, POST or otherwise, I need to provide this `api_key` in order for the call to authenticate server-side.

```
// Have to figure out a way to get this into my HttpClient call,
// regardless of whether I'm using: HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut
// or HttpDelete...
String api_key = "blah-whatever-my-unique-api-key";
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to provide `HttpClient` with the `api_key` regardless of my request method (which in turn depends on which RESTful API method I'm trying to hit). It looks like `HttpGet` doesn't even *support* the notion of parameters, and `HttpPost` uses something called `HttpParams`; but again these `HttpParams` only seem to exist in 3.x.x version of `HttpClient`.

So I ask: **What is the proper, v4.2.2 way to attach/add my `api_key` String to all four**:

- `HttpGet`
- `HttpPost`
- `HttpPut`
- `HttpDelete`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use ***URIBuilder*** class to build the request URI for all the HTTP methods. URI builder provides ***setParameter*** method to set the parameter.

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http").setHost("www.google.com").setPath("/search")
    .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
    .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
    .setParameter("aq", "f")
    .setParameter("oq", "");
URI uri = builder.build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

The output should be

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=
```

Comment: Thanks @rboorgapally (+1) - however I believe this only works for `HttpGet` (setting the parameters on the query string), and would have no effect for `HttpPost`, `HttpPut` or `HttpDelete`. Although each of these have a constructor that accepts a `URI` as an argument, I do not believe `URIBuilder` implicitly knows to convert query string parameters to, say, `HttpPost` POST variables, etc. So althought I would be passing the non-`HttpGet` methods a URI with the full query string, I do not believe they will know how to convert that query string into a data format they know how to work with.

Comment: I will just like to add that `setParameter` overrides the existing value. So if one wants to set a `List` variable in URI like `/search?q=1&q=2&y=3`, so here `q` is a list and it's final value will be 2 not [1,2]. To avoid this one may use `addParameter` method of the URIBuilder. Docs: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#addParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: So is this answer applicable for non-get requests or not?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this approach in case you want to pass some http parameters and send a json request:

(note: I have added in some extra code just incase it helps any other future readers and imports are from org.apache.http client libraries)

```
public void postJsonWithHttpParams() throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    //add the http parameters you wish to pass
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "param1_value"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "param2_value"));

    //Build the server URI together with the parameters you wish to pass
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("http://google.ug");
    uriBuilder.addParameters(postParameters);

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
    postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    //this is your JSON string you are sending as a request
    String yourJsonString = "{\"str1\":\"a value\",\"str2\":\"another value\"} ";

    //pass the json string request in the entity
    HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(yourJsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);

    //create a socketfactory in order to use an http connection manager
    PlainConnectionSocketFactory plainSocketFactory = PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> connSocketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", plainSocketFactory)
            .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(connSocketFactoryRegistry);

    connManager.setMaxTotal(20);
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(HttpClientPool.connTimeout)
            .setConnectTimeout(HttpClientPool.connTimeout)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(HttpClientPool.readTimeout)
            .build();

    // Build the http client.
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
            .build();

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);

    //Read the response
    String responseString = "";

    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String message = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

    HttpEntity responseHttpEntity = response.getEntity();

    InputStream content = responseHttpEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;

    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        responseString += line;
    }

    //release all resources held by the responseHttpEntity
    EntityUtils.consume(responseHttpEntity);

    //close the stream
    response.close();

    // Close the connection manager.
    connManager.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An important thing here is to say explictly the apache's packages you must use, because there are different ways to implement a get request.

For example, you could use `Apache Commons` or `HttpComponents`. 
In this example, I will use `HttpComponents (org.apache.http.*)`

**Request class:**

```
package request;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import Task;

public void sendRequest(Task task) throws URISyntaxException {

    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
    uriBuilder.setScheme("http")
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setPort(8080)
            .setPath("/TesteHttpRequest/TesteDoLucas")
            .addParameter("className", task.getClassName())
            .addParameter("dateExecutionBegin", task.getDateExecutionBegin())
            .addParameter("dateExecutionEnd", task.getDateExecutionEnd())
            .addParameter("lastDateExecution", task.getDateLastExecution())
            .addParameter("numberExecutions", Integer.toString(task.getNumberExecutions()))
            .addParameter("idTask", Integer.toString(task.getIdTask()))
            .addParameter("numberExecutions" , Integer.toString(task.getNumberExecutions()));
    URI uri = uriBuilder.build();

    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(uri);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(getMethod);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle this IOException properly in the future
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle this IOException properly in the future
    }
}
```

I'm using Tomcat v7.0 Server, then the class above receives a task and sends it to a specific servlet in the link *http://localhost:8080/TesteHttpRequest/TesteDoLucas*.

My Dynamic Web project is named *TesteHttpRequest* and my servlet attends by the url */TesteDoLucas*

**Task class:**

```
package bean;

public class Task {

    private int idTask;
    private String taskDescription;
    private String dateExecutionBegin;
    private String dateExecutionEnd;
    private String dateLastExecution;
    private int numberExecutions;
    private String className;

    public int getIdTask() {
        return idTask;
    }

    public void setIdTask(int idTask) {
        this.idTask = idTask;
    }

    public String getTaskDescription() {
        return taskDescription;
    }

    public void setTaskDescription(String taskDescription) {
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
    }

    public String getDateExecutionBegin() {
        return dateExecutionBegin;
    }

    public void setDateExecutionBegin(String dateExecutionBegin) {
        this.dateExecutionBegin = dateExecutionBegin;
    }

    public String getDateExecutionEnd() {
        return dateExecutionEnd;
    }

    public void setDateExecutionEnd(String dateExecutionEnd) {
        this.dateExecutionEnd = dateExecutionEnd;
    }

    public String getDateLastExecution() {
        return dateLastExecution;
    }

    public void setDateLastExecution(String dateLastExecution) {
        this.dateLastExecution = dateLastExecution;
    }

    public int getNumberExecutions() {
        return numberExecutions;
    }

    public void setNumberExecutions(int numberExecutions) {
        this.numberExecutions = numberExecutions;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }
}
```

**Servlet class:**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/TesteDoLucas")
public class TesteHttpRequestServlet extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String query = request.getQueryString();
        System.out.println(query);
     }

     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
        }
    }
```

The query parameters sent will be shown at console.

> className=java.util.Objects%3B&dateExecutionBegin=2016%2F04%2F07+22%3A22%3A22&dateExecutionEnd=2016%2F04%2F07+06%3A06%3A06&lastDateExecution=2016%2F04%2F07+11%3A11%3A11&numberExecutions=10&idTask=1&numberExecutions=10

To fix the encoding, you can look at here: [HttpServletRequest UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527576/httpservletrequest-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: How different is your answer from the existing one? What value does it aggregate? You should have kept the focus on adding the parameters to the request. The `Task` class is irrelevant in the context of the question.

Comment: I posted this question because I have tem same doubt days ago and every question I found answered in stackoverflow ignored the whole process of sending the request. I mean, the part of adding new parameters was right, but had to search in another topics how to complete the request (and I only found in the oficial documentation) and it took me time. It aggregates a lot in the way that you  can copy and paste it and have a real funcional example of the request made with you get parameters, saving you time of searching details in the documentation. The task class is irrelevant, but helps to e.g.