# HttpServletRequest UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, httprequest

I want to get my parameters from the request (characters with accents) but it doesn't work. I tried to user `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` but it didn't work either.

I know that `URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8")` returns the right characters, but `request.getParameterValues()` doesn't work!

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Paul's suggestion seems like the best course of action, but if you're going to work around it, you don't need URLEncoder or URLDecoder at all:

```
String item = request.getParameter("param"); 

byte[] bytes = item.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
item = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Java 6:
// byte[] bytes = item.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
// item = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

**Update:** Since this is getting a lot of votes, I want to stress BalusC's point that this definitely is not a solution;  it is a workaround at best.  People should not be doing this.

I don't know exactly what caused the original issue, but I suspect the URL was already UTF-8 encoded, and then was UTF-8 encoded again.

Comment: To all future readers, please note that this is a workaround, not a solution. In fact, an extremely terrible one which makes your webapp brittle and unportable.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using Apache Tomcat, `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` only works with `POST` request.

For `GET` request, you need add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` on your `<Connector>` in `server.xml`.

See more in [*FAQ/CharacterEncoding - Apache Tomcat wiki space*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding#CharacterEncoding-Q2).

Comment: How about WebSphere Application Server? May I know the server.xml is located at which folder in WAS ? I search for whole, found that there is a lot of server.xml.

Comment: With WebSphere, you need to use the system property `client.encoding.override`. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzatz/51/admin/help/trun_svr_utf.html

Comment: @PaulVargas Hi, the link you provided is now dead, returns 404. Could you kindly update the resource? Thanks!

Comment: @SajibAcharya Hi! -- Thanks for the heads-up. Apparently, some sort of [migration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Migrated+Content). But we can see the *original* at [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190618043706/https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2).

Answer (score 9):

Well, I found a way to resolve my problem, I guess that's not the better solution, but it does works..

```
  String item = request.getParameterValues("param"); // HÃ©lÃ¨ne
  item = URLEncoder.encode( model.getNameItem(), "ISO-8859-1" ); // H%C3%A9l%C3%A8ne
  item = URLDecoder.decode( item, "UTF-8" ); // and finally : Hélène
```

If it can help anyone else, I'm glad to help :)

PS : Paul, I didn't answer you earlier but I already did those things. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: From Paul answer, May I know the server.xml is located at which folder in WAS ? I search for whole, found that there is a lot of server.xml.

Comment: Worked for me, thx. I couldn't modify the Tomcat server, so this is perfect :)