# How to pass UTF8 string in URL to JSP page

Tags: jsp, utf-8

I have a simple dashboard with items, and each item can have several tags. Now I'm implementing filtering functionality, when user clicks a tag, all item with that will be shown.

At the server side I'm rendering the webpage using JSTL `<c:url />` with `<c:param />` so in the source code it looks like this:

```
<a href="/dashboard?filter=k%c5%af%c5%88">kůň</a>
```

The problem is, that when I click the link, my browser actually decodes the string and it sends following to server: `/dashboard?filter=kůň`

The thing it, that this isn't valid URL so on the way over network it gets mangled and the server actually recieves `/dashboard?filter=kÅ¯Å`.

Everything on my webpage and server is set to use UTF-8. And this problem doesn't happen when using POST and sending UTF-8 data from form.

Is there any way to stop the browser from decoding the string?

I have tried Firefox and Chrome, but I don't think it's of any significance.

UPDATE: To clarify I want to recieve percent encoded string on my server, so I can safely decode it.

UPDATE2: I did some research on the letters, the problem is. That `LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE` (ů) is encoded as two bytes - `0xC5 0xAF`. And Java treats each byte as single character. So `0xC5` becomes `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE` - Å. And so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpServletRequest UTF-8 Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527576/httpservletrequest-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I have found solution in this question: [HttpServletRequest UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527576/httpservletrequest-utf-8-encoding)

So far the best idea I have for solving this program, would be to discard the fulltext from QueryString. I can replace the tag string with corresponding ID from database, which in turn will solve the encoding problem.