# JPA EntityManager and character encoding

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

For the first time, I'm creating a simple website with JSP, Servlets, a Tomcat server, MySQL and Netbeans (if that helps).

Thanks to JPA **EntityManager**, I can insert data into my database like this :

```
    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test").createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(usr);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Where usr is an Entity Class *User* generated thanks to Netbeans. 
Everything works perfectly except the fact that it doesn't support characters such as accents.

Assuming I want to insert the word "cliché" :

- If I try to print the value from my *User* class, everything is fine.
- When the value is sent, if I try to SELECT the value from my base, I've got strange characters instead of the "é"

Database fields are **utf8_unicode_ci**. If I try to make a simple INSERT from MySQL prompt such as

```
INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES("ééé");
```

it's working perfectly.

As I read on some websites, I modified my **persistence.xml** with the following line :

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
```

but the result is the same.

EDIT : Here are the properties of my *User Class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByIdUsers", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.idUsers = :idUsers"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPasswd", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.passwd = :passwd"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.firstName = :firstName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLastName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.lastName = :lastName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmailAndPwd", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email AND u.passwd = :passwd")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "postal")
    private String postal;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idUsers")
    private Integer idUsers;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "passwd")
    private String passwd;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
```

As I read on the web, I also tried to modify my **catalina.bat** by adding the following lines but it didn't change anything.

> set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In Glassfish I use this on WEB-INF-->glassfish-web.xml  <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/> Maybe it´s similar in tomcat

Comment: I couldn't find a similar property for Tomcat

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, so I'll take some long shots: What version of MySQL are you using?  What version of the MySQL JDBC driver are you using?  Exactly what strange characters do you see?  (By any chance are you seeing `clichÃ©`?)

Comment: @VGR My MySQL version is 5.6 (the last one). For the driver, the version is 5.1.34. And as you said, the characters are "Ã©" for "é"

Comment: "Ã©" is a Latin-1 interpretation of the two UTF-8 bytes which represent "é".  This has me wondering if perhaps your column and/or table is actually using Latin-1 (a.k.a. ISO 8859-1).  Does a statement that uses non-Latin-1 characters work, such as `INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES("↑↑↑");`?

Comment: Yes, it actually works.. 
I just read your previous answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527576/httpservletrequest-utf-8-encoding/16549329#16549329 and it fixed my problem. I don't really get what was the issue. I made sure that all my columns and tables are using UTF-8.
As you helped me a lot, I let you add the answer so that I can accept it ! Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem thanks to VGR's answer here : [HttpServletRequest UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527576/httpservletrequest-utf-8-encoding/16549329#16549329)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: To all future readers, please note that this is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try add this config in your persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using JPA without Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add unicode encoding filter to web.xml:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
  </filter>
```

if you use Spring you can use 'org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter' class to encode all requests, else you should use other encoding class.