# UTF-8 Encoding for GET Requests

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, utf-8

We are using Servlet and JSP in our project and we need to make changes in all the JSP Page from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8.

We are not facing any issue for POST Requests but for GET Request we have a problem. and we should not touch Server configuration file.

is there anyway we can support UTF-8 without altering server configuration file?

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527576/httpservletrequest-utf-8-encoding

Comment: It helped a lot.. Thank you so much amit :)