# Unable to print text with quotes in Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, string, servlets, escaping

I have a web application where the user will insert any text, including quotes etc. I am sending these to the database. Anyway all my quotes are being replaced with `â??` no matter what I do. I tried the below with the use of `apache commons-text` still no good. I believe I tried all methods there, only thing happened was getting them printed with different characters instead of `â??`. I am trying to pass the text `overweight or obese, ‘apple shaped’, have unhealthy eating habits`

```
String message = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(request.getParameter("message"));
System.out.println(message);
```

The result is simple as `â??apple shapedâ??`

How can I solve this matter?

Comment: This looks more like a charset problem - what charset are you using?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I didn't specify anything specifically. How to set that?

Comment: well I am not sure that you needs to ;-) Please show the exact text that is being entered

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Here we go with actual text, `overweight or obese, ‘apple shaped’, have unhealthy eating habits`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of

Comment: @ScaryWombat: No, that's not the case unfortunatly. Im using UTF 8 in JSP

Comment: UTF8 in jsp but what about in your servlet? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549329/2310289

Comment: Are you using tomcat by any chance?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Thanks, that was the answer. Please provide the comment as an answer.

Comment: @MauricePerry: Yes, things worked with `ScaryWombat` answer