# How can I be sure that an HttpClient PostMethod contains UTF-8 strings in the parameters?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

In our webapp, we have to send a POST request via HttpClient to an endpoint on our network, which will receive this and do some work with it. We are having trouble with character encoding, and I am having difficulties finding an answer to my question.

We have used the `postMethod.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8")` method when sending the request, but on the receiving end, it seems like the characters are still encoded in ISO 8859-1. I have determined this because when I inspect the String on the receiving side, it has garbage characters in it that go away once I follow the steps found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549329/1130549. Is there any extra steps I need to take on the sending end to ensure that I am actually writing characters in UTF-8 as expected? All we are doing now is using `postMethod.addParameter(paramKey, paramValue)` with native `String` objects.

Edit: Here is a very simple example of how we're sending the POST request. For what it's worth, the values are being taken from an XMLBeans object.

```
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);
postMethod.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");
postMethod.addParameter("key1", "value1");
postMethod.addParameter("key2", "value2");

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
int status = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Simpler solution is to encode the value

```
postMethod.addParameter("key1", URLEncoder.encode("value1","UTF-8"));
```

To encode properly UTF-8, you can execute differently, using `StringEntity` and `NameValuePair`, e.g.:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build()) {
   URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
   HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uriBuilder.getHost(), uriBuilder.getPort(), uriBuilder.getScheme());
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2"));
   String entityValue = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
   StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(entityValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
   post.setEntity(entity);
   httpClient.execute(target, post);
```

Comment: But isn't this using the request body instead of the request parameters? This is a completely different implementation.

Comment: @agent154 See `postMethod.addParameter` https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html#addParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) *Adds a new parameter to be used in the POST request body.*

Comment: @agent154 simpler solution is to encode the value `postMethod.addParameter("key1", URLEncoder.encode("value1","UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do need to make sure that the string that you are actually writing is encoded in UTF-8. I realized that you already know that but still double-check that it is so, as it would be the prime suspect of your problem. Also, I would recommend trying a much simpler HTTP client. Apache HTTP client (I believe that's the library that you are using) is an excellent library. But due to covering a very wide range of options it tends to be a bit bulky. So, or simple requests I would suggest a lightweight HTTP client that maybe not that comprehensive as Apache library but offers simplicity as a trade-off. Here how your code may look like:

```
    private static void testHttpClient() {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
//      client.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        client.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        client.setConnectionUrl("http://www.my-url.com");
        String content = null;
        try {
            String myMessage = getMyMessage() // get the string that you want to send
            content = client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.POST, myMessage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            content = client.getLastResponseMessage() + TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, false);
        }
        System.out.println(content);
    }
```

It looks much more simple, I think. Also in the same library, there is another utility that allows you to convert any string in any language into a sequence of unicodes and vice-versa. This helped me numerous times to diagnose encoding thorny issues. For instance, if you see some gibberish symbols that could be a wrong display of a valid character or actual character loss. Here is an example of how it works:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

That might help you to check if the string you passed is valid or not. The library is called MgntUtils and could be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.8/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and Javadoc. Javadoc could be found separately [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/)
**Disclaimer**: The MgntUtils library is written by me